# What are the consequences of breaking ABI calling conventions?

Tags: compiler-construction, calling-convention, abi

I'm doing some compiler-writing projects and I want to make sure I'm understanding ABI and calling-conventions correctly.

Say I'm writing a compiler for some high-level language **L**, and it's targeting some system **S**.

If I'm understanding things correctly, as long as I'm generating instructions for **L** methods that are calling other **L** methods, I can use whatever calling conventions I want. The only time I'd have to follow the standard calling conventions specified by **S**'s ABI is whenever I want to make a system call or call a foreign function that adheres to the ABI's calling convention.

Is this understanding correct? And furthermore, are there any negative consequences of a language runtime having a different internal calling convention besides the obvious compatibility with foreign functions?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your language, you can use whatever calling convention you like internally, within the constraints of the hardware and operating system (see [@RaymondChen's comment for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863544/what-are-the-consequences-of-breaking-abi-calling-conventions/72864037#comment128698228_72864037)). You don't even have to be consistent if you know you can see all the call sites of a function.

But:

- If you want to call foreign functions, you need to also implement their calling conventions (and name mangling, if required).
- If you want foreign functions to be able to call your functions (including whatever you use asa top-level function), you need to implement do what they expect you to do. So you'll probably need something like C++'s `extern "<language>"` syntax to mark foreign-callables.

System calls usually have their own calling procedure; typically, this involves using a special-purpose opcode which raises an interrupt. Standard libraries usually include wrappers for system calls, but if you have some syntax for declaring the calling convention of a function, you could use that for system calls as well, although it would limit portability.

But none of that is an argument against creating your own ABI. Indeed, your language design might depend on features which cannot be efficiently implemented without a custom ABI (exceptions, coroutines, delimited continuations, generators, async procedures, etc., etc.).

Comment: The operating system itself may impose rules that apply at interrupt or fault time (e.g. for signal handlers). For example, you probably cannot have a 64KB red zone or use the stack pointer as a general purpose register.

Comment: @raymond: true. Your freedom is a bit constrained. But it's not constrained by another language's ABI. I'll edit that line.